# Java Packets mess

Tags: java

I am programming a server in Java. Here's my main thread code :

```
public class EntryThread extends Thread {

    volatile byte[] toSend;

    public EntryThread() {

    }

    public void TreatRequest(byte[] data, InetAddress IPAddress)
    {
        try {
            switch (data[0])
            {
                case 0: // ping
                    toSend = new byte[] { (byte) 255, data[1], (byte) 255};
                    Server.serverSocket.send(new DatagramPacket(toSend, 3, IPAddress, 17550));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception because of a packet malformation issue. You can ignore it.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() { 
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){public void run(){ 
            try {
                Server.serverSocket.close();
                System.out.println("The server is shut down!");
            } catch (Exception e) { /* failed */ }
        }});

        try {
            Server.serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(Configuration.port);

            byte[] receiveData = new byte[512];

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                               receiveData.length);
            while(true) {
                Server.serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                byte[] data = receivePacket.getData();
                System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + new String(data));
                InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();

                /*
                 * data[0] : command/255 if 
                 * data[1] : C-ID.
                 * data[2] : arguments/content
                 */

                TreatRequest(data, IPAddress);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

All seems good, but when I send packets with some software (PacketSender), it's starting to become weird. Here's my console :

```
RECEIVED: [][][][][][]... // I sent 00 in hex, no problem there)
RECEIVED: ÿ[]ÿ[][][][]... // here's the response of the server)
RECEIVED: [][]ÿ[][][][]... // this ÿ is still there even if I just sent 00 in hex.
```

So it only overwrites on a array I'm forced to make it big.

So I would like to know :

- How can I make the packet date to be reset to lots of 0s each time ?
- Can I just get an array of the size of the packet, instead of this weird "pass the array as an argument" method ?

Comment: On your console listing it is unclear what is the actual output and what is your commenton the output.  Please reformat to clearly separate the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer used by `DatagramPacket` is not cleared each time a packet is received.  However, the method `getLength()` tells you how much data was received in the current packet, and you should be using that to limit what you extract from the buffer.  For your example:

```
System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + new String(data,0,receivePacket.getLength()));
```

Comment: If the length is 1, I should do a -1 to the getLength?

Comment: No, if the length is 1, use 1.  Read the definition of the `String(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [receive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive-java.net.DatagramPacket-) javadoc:

> The length field of the datagram packet object contains the length of
>   the received message.

`System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + new String(data, 0, receivePacket.getLength()));`